# PowerShell equivalent of Unix shell buitin 'type'

Tags: command-line, powershell

When working in a POSIX shell, I can use the builtin `type` to see how an executable, shell function, builtin, or alias is defined.

For instance, I have a shell function `box`, which will draw an ASCII box around a given piece of text:

```
$ box "I am the operator of my pocket calculator"
#############################################
# I am the operator of my pocket calculator #
#############################################
```

and I can see how the function is defined like this:

```
$ type box
box is a function
box ()
{
    t="$1xxxx";
    c=${2:-#};
    echo ${t//?/$c};
    echo "$c $1 $c";
    echo ${t//?/$c}
}
```

Is there a PowerShell equivalent? I'm particularly interested in seeing PowerShell functions that I have defined in `$profile`, and seeing how they are defined -- I've been using

```
type $profile
```

to show all of them, but I want something a little more targeted. (Note that the PowerShell/Cmd command `type` is equivalent to the Unix `cat` and is ***not in any way related*** to the Unix `type` builtin that I'm asking about.)

Comment: if all you  want is the text of a file, then look at this example ... >>> `Get-Content -LiteralPath $profile` <<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every command is a function.

In order to find out if your command is indeed a function, type:

```
get-command "name of command"
```

For example:

```
PS> get-command box_

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Box
```

Now that we have determined that it is indeed a function, you can see the content of the function like this:

```
(get-command box).ScriptBlock
```

See also: https://www.pdq.com/blog/viewing-powershell-function-contents/

Personally, I added the following to my Powershell Profile:

```
cls
write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Powershell started with custom functions."
write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "They are: EditCustomFunctions, name1, name2, etc..."

function EditCustomFunctions
{
    if (!(Test-Path (Split-Path $profile))) { mkdir (Split-Path $profile) } ; if (!(Test-Path $profile)) { New-Item $profile -ItemType file } ; powershell_ise $profile

}
```

So from within Powershell I can just type EditCustomFuctions to open PowerShell ISE with my profile to edit the functions, and my custom welcome message lists all my custom functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted LPChip's answer because he gave me exactly the information that I needed; I'm adding a PowerShell function here that I'm actually going to use -- it's just a thin wrapper around `Get-Command` that does the `CommandType` check before printing the `ScriptBlock`.

```
function showfunc {
    param($function_name)

    $command=Get-Command "$function_name"
    if ($command.CommandType  -match "Function") { $command.ScriptBlock }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me as a token of appreciation. :)